# Using same viewmodel on different fragments

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, viewmodel

I have viewModel on Fragment A, which I load in this way:

```
viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, viewModelFactory).get(AFragmentVM::class.java)
```

then from fragment A, I go to fragment B. Is this possible to use the same viewmodel on fragment B? In Fragment B I tried (as in docs):

```
private val viewModel: AFragmentVM by activityViewModels()
```

but I get an exception while trying to use this ViewModel:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class ...AFragmentVM
...
BFragment.getViewModel(Unknown Source:2)
BFragment.onCreateView(ChartFragment.kt:40)
...
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: ...AFragmentVM.<init> [class android.app.Application]
```

**EDIT:**

Based on @SebastienRieu and @IntelliJ Amiya answers, everything that I had to do was to create ViewModel on Fragment A in this way:

```
viewModel = ViewModelProvider(requireActivity(), viewModelFactory).get(AFragmentVM::class.java)
```

Or:

```
viewModel  = ViewModelProvider(let {activity}!!,viewModelFactory).get(AFragmentVM::class.java)
```

Then on Fragment B I could use:

```
private val viewModel: AFragmentVM by activityViewModels()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the two fragments are in the same activity you should replace this :

```
viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, viewModelFactory).get(AFragmentVM::class.java)
```

by this

```
viewModel = ViewModelProvider(requireActivity(), viewModelFactory).get(AFragmentVM::class.java)
```

and add a viewModel in the activity and initialize it in this activity like this :

```
viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, viewModelFactory).get(AFragmentVM::class.java)
```

With **requireActivity()** when setup the VM in fragment you tell the fragment to use the activity shared ViewModel

Comment: Yes, there are in the same activity but I have an instance of `viewModelFactory` only in Fragment A. So I have to create viewmodel in activity and move viewModelFactory to the activity?

Comment: Yes, this is what you have to do !

Answer (score 1):

Fragment A

```
viewModel  = ViewModelProvider(let {activity}!!,viewModelFactory).get(AFragmentVM::class.java)
```

Fragment B

```
 private lateinit var viewModel: AFragmentVM
```